# Printing a dictionary to a CSV file when some keys have more than one value

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file, from which I am reading some fields (columns) into a dictionary (so that one column serves as a key and other as a value). To be more precise, I have keys in numerical format and values in string format. But I have one issue here. In the CSV file, I have cases where the same number is associated with more than one string. So when I tried to print my dictionary to an output.csv file, it is indeed printing it as I desire (key:value) format, but it ignores the cases where the key has more than one value associated with it. From what I observed, only the latest value associated with that key is preserved and the older values were overwritten.

For example: 
999 Test1
999 Test1
999 Test2
999 Test3

In this case only 999:Test3 is printed on output.csv file. What I need is if a case like this arises, it should print a message on the output.csv file, something like this.

999: Has more than one tests

How can I implement this? Here's the code I have written so far, to print out the dictionary to output file. But I need some help to incorporate the above desired result.

```
import csv

infile = open('input.csv',"rb")
reader = csv.reader(infile)

outfile = open('output.csv',"wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

mydict = dict((rows[18],rows[19]) for rows in reader)
for key,value in mydict.items():
    writer.writerow([key,value])

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that in the input file, since you're reading columns 18 & 19, there can be rows that have the same value in column 18 as a previous row?

Comment: Well dicts in python have unique keys, so you can't have more than Test assigned to a key. You can however assign a list to a key. So you could do something like 999 [Test1, Test1, Test2, Test3].

Comment: @mauve: Yes, you are right. I want to identify such rows and print the error message accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just keep a tab on the already found keys and test for them:

```
import csv

infile = open('input.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(infile)

outfile = open('output.csv', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

found_keys = {}
for rows in reader:
    k, v = rows[18], rows[19]
    if k in found_keys and found_keys[k] != v:
        print("found duplicate key {} with different values {} , {}".format(k, v, found_keys[k]))
    else:
        found_keys[k] = v
        writer.writerow([k, v])   

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: What if I have keys and values like this?                                                         999 Test1  999 Test1 999 Test1                                                                             In this case I do not want an error message printing up. I want the error message only if a key has more than one "unique" values.

Comment: Thank you @RickyA. I think I am on right track now. I will take it from there.